# Как вывести будущую дату в PHP и ежедневно минусовать дату?

Tags: php, datetime

Имеется переменная: `$DT["datetime"]`, которая выводит дату в миллисекундах, при выводе посредством `date("f-m-Y", $DT["datetime"]) //26-03-2021` выводит дату занесения информации в бд, как средствами php **узнать будущую дату, которая наступает через 1-календарный месяц**? И какими средствами можно сминусовать дату ежедневно от `$END_DATE` до `$START_DATE`, чтобы получилось по дням (**например осталось: 20 дней до наступления** `$END_DATE`)

Comment: А зачем вам минусовать то? У вас есть записана дата, и вы при загрузке страницы/скрипта сравниваете текущую дату и записанную

Comment: надо получается

Comment: в поисках решения проблемы, нужно для здачи работы по PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
// "сегодня", или же текущая дата
$date = date("d-m-Y", time());
echo $date . PHP_EOL;
// дата какого-то события: сегодня + 1 месяц
$evtDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date . " +1MONTH"));
echo $evtDate . PHP_EOL;
// считаем сколько осталось до события
$left = strtotime($evtDate) - time();
// "переводим" время в дни
$left = floor($left/(60*60*24));
echo 'Осталось '. $left . " дней до ". $evtDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$event = new DateTimeImmutable('+1 month');
$left = $event->diff(new DateTimeImmutable());

echo $event->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
echo "{$left->days} days left", PHP_EOL;
```